# How can I specify a broken time series?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have survey data collected for many species from 9 surveys within a 11 month period. The surveys span a period that begins in December and ends the following October. There are no data from May or June for any of the species.  The following is a simplified example, though my data has many columns of abundance data.

the dates

```
month <- c("Dec10", "Jan11", "Feb11", "Mar11", "Apr11", "Jul11", "Aug11", "Sep11", "Oct11")
```

codified using `as.yearmon` from the package zoo

```
require(zoo)
month <- as.yearmon(month, "%b%y")
```

some fake abundance data

```
meanAbund <- rlnorm(9, 1, 1.2)
meanAbund2 <- meanAbund + 0.5  # to have two series at least
```

all joined together

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(meanAbund, meanAbund2, month)
```

Although I appreciate that this time sequence is not long enough to undertake time series analysis, I would like to specify that these data are a (broken) time series object so that graphs will break the series rather than interpolate or ignore the gap. How should this be done?

I suspect that this should be easy, but I have not cracked the solution. What I want to produce can be seen on page 4 of Shah, Zeileis and Grothendieck's [quick reference guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf) for the zoo package, but I can't see in which step their examples are informed by the code.

I can read it as a time series object

```
df.ts <- zoo(df[ , 1:2], df$month])
```

and plot the series (up to the 63 from my actual dataset, although the output is as hard to consider as you might suspect),

```
plot.zoo(df.ts)
```

but the series ignore the gaps.

How should i specify the graph or read in these data so that plotting functions "know" to break the series?

Comment: Please provide your plotting code

Comment: @HubertL I have now edited my post to provide steps through to the plot that I had produced (although tidied up following Pierre Lafortune's example). I can get breaks in a "single" plot -- or multiple empty frames -- using `plot.ts`, or multiple plots without breaks using `plot.zoo`. That now looks to be a different question or problem.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `zoo` allows for the order of your data. A gap will be inserted for you for the missing dates:

```
df
      Date Value
1 Jan 2005     1
2 Feb 2005     2
3 Mar 2005     3
5 May 2005     5
6 Jun 2005     6
```

Create zoo time series:

```
library(zoo)
df.ts <- zoo(df$Value, df$Date)
```

Plot

```
ts.plot(df.ts)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(2005, 2005.08333333333, 2005.16666666667, 
                                        2005.33333333333, 2005.41666666667), class = "yearmon"), Value = c(1L, 
                                                                                                           2L, 3L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("Date", "Value"), row.names = c("1", 
                                                                                                                                                                        "2", "3", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
df$Date <- as.yearmon(df$Date, "%b %Y")
```

Comment: how did you specify df$Date originally? I am trying to replicate your suggestion in order to understand the differences between `plot.ts`, which will recognise the breaks as your example above shows, and `plot.zoo`, which seems to ignore them.

Comment: The column must be in a recognized date format. Check answer

Comment: However, it looks to me that a recognized date format is not enough when using `plot.zoo`, but the resolution of that part of the problem I should probably present as a separate post.